# Patch an install4j uninstaller application possible?

Tags: install4j

We detected a bug within our uninstall routine of one of our released products. Now we are thinking about providing a patch to fix this bug in the uninstaller application of install4j. In generally is this possible? We don't want to make changes to our main application only to replace the *uninstaller.exe*. I thought about to create an addon installer do nothing but to install a new uninstaller executable. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Congratulations, you asked question number 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable `uninstaller.exe` does not contain your uninstaller logic. All screens and actions are contained in the file `.install4j/i4jparams.conf`. You can replace that file with an add-on installer.

Comment: That sounds good. But how can we create this config file? Is it created during a install4j build? Or do we have to copy it from an existing installation, modify it and use this file as our source to override it by the addon installation?

Comment: You would have to copy it from an existing installation and add it to the distribution tree of the add-on installer.

Comment: Another idea: what about to modify this file directly with the xml modification action of install4j? Is this possible or recommandable?

Comment: Sure you can do that with the "Replace text in XML files" action. To get the XPath expression I would recommend IntelliJ IDEA and the "Show unique Xpath expression" action in the context menu when editing the i4jparams.conf file as an XML file.

Comment: Okay, I understand how to replace values or nodes inside the `i4jparams.conf`. But we need to change a validation script or file filter script and for this purpose, the scripts are located as class files inside the `user.jar`, right? So we can't do a patch by simply editing the configuration file?

Comment: Is it possible to reimplenting the script functionality by using the install4j api (and how?), compile the java class to get the `.class`-file during our maven build, copy the class file to the `user.jar` by using the _modify zip file_ action during the addon installation process and changing the beanclass references inside the `i4jparams.conf` file?

Comment: The Modify ZIP file action will work for updating the class file of a script. If the project did not change the number of scripts or their order, the script number should remain the same.

Comment: So we have to change the script in our project, build and install the project, extract the "new" class from the archive file and include it to our addon installer. Is that right? There is no way we can implement the script as an own class without doing the workaround with the base project?

Comment: Yes you can do that, too. To get started, I would decompile an existing script, you can then modify it.